# Can't login using OAuth2PasswordGrant class

Tags: ios, oauth, swift3

I am using https://github.com/p2/OAuth2 library in Swift 3 project. I initialized OAuth2PasswordGrant with settings with username, password, client_id, client_secret, authorize_uri and keychain. And called the authorize function. The error I got was unsupported_grant_type.

```
self.oAuth = OAuth2PasswordGrant(settings: settings)
self.oAuth.authorize { (json: OAuth2JSON?, error: OAuth2Error?) in
    // did sth here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings data structure. My experience was i passed in a URL into authorize_uri instead of a string, and the authorize_uri defaulted to localhost. That was an invalid target and resulted in an *unsupported_grant_type* error